# Jquery - Accessing nested child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume I have the following HTML -

```
<DIV id="ParentDiv">
    <DIV id="SubDiv1"></DIV>
    <DIV id="SubDiv2">
        <INPUT id="input">
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

To access the input element using jquery, it would be simply $("#input"). What I'm trying to do is access it, assuming I only know the ID of the top level div.

Currently I have

```
$($($("#ParentDiv").children()[1]).children()[0])
```

Which does seem to work. Is there a cleaner way of writing this, or is the way I am doing it ok?

Comment: i think `$("#ParentDiv").find('input')` also works

Comment: Have a browse through the [list of jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) - you'll see things like the [`":eq()" selector`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) which lets you do this: `$("#ParentDiv > div:eq(1) > input")`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You would just perform a `.find()` implicitly or explicitly:

```
$('#ParentDiv input');  // implicitly

$('#ParentDiv').find('input'); // explicitly
```

Reference: [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 9):

You can try:

```
1. $('#ParentDiv input')
2. $('input', '#ParentDiv')
3. $('#ParentDiv').find('input')
```

Answer (score 6):

if you need to find the input from `SubDiv2` only upon having parentDiv information you can use

```
$("#ParentDiv div:eq(1) input")
```

or

```
$("#ParentDiv div:eq(1)").find("input")
```

Where eq(1) will get you with the second div inside ParentDiv

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 $('#ParentDiv').find('input');
```

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to do it. Here is one

```
$("#ParentDiv > div:eq(1) > input")
```

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
$("#ParentDiv :input")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery('#input').val();
```